# Rows cannot be added programmatically in the DataGridView when the control data-bound

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview

In my DatagridView already have data, then i want to add new row when click add button in windows form i got "Rows cannot add programmatically to the datagridview row collection when in the controls data-bound.

Then i google it i got some answer like you can use DataTable to add a new row, below code i used

Then, i tried to run,

in my datagrid shows rows added but with blank values for all rows like a empty row

kindly suggest me where i'm wrong i'm new at windows application datagridview with c#

```
DataTable dataTable=new DataTable();

 foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView.Columns)
 {
     dataTable.Column.add(col.Name);
 }
 foreach (dataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
 {
     DataRow drow=dataTable.NewRow();
     foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.cells)
     {
        drow[cell.ColumnIndes]=cell.value;
        dataTable.Rows.add(drow);
     }
 }
   //then,
   //i assigned dataTable values to dataGridView

   dataGridView.DataSource=dataTable;
 }
```

Comment: Your post is not very clear.  Typically, you have a DataTable, you bind it to the DGV and henceforth add change and delete the datasource.  Yuur code seems to be trying to create a datatable from the DGV - backwards!.  Where did the DGV data come from?

Comment: As Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp points out, the posted code appears to be doing things backwards. Typically, you would get a `DataSource` from something like a database or file, then query the data base or read the file data into some type of data structure like a `DataTable` or `List<T>`. Then you would use the `DataTable` or `List<T>` as a `DataSource` to the grid.

Comment: The error you describe implies that the grid HAS a `DataSource`, therefore the error is saying you can not add rows directly to grid, instead you have to add rows directly to the `DataSource` not the grid. Once the data has been added to the data source, then the new row should display in the grid. You may have to reset the grids `DataSource` to reflect this newly added row.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get why you do all of these things.
You said you have data in your dataGridView, Mean you have already set headers of the dataGridView and you just want to add new row while clicking on the button.
If my perception is right then you just do the below thing on button click event.

```cs
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Column1", "Column2",..);
```